# Dequeued UICollectionViewCell not refreshed

Tags: ios, objective-c, refresh, uicollectionview

I have an application with a `UICollectionView` with horizontal scroll of cells (Only one cell is displayed at a time). Each cell hosts a `UITableView` which displays content (URL links) in each of the `UITableViewCell`. 
The problem is that the first two cells of `UICollectionView` display the proper content, but starting from the third cell, the contents are displayed from the dequeued cells. The correct content on the dequeued cell's `UITableView` is only displayed if user scrolls down and then scrolls up to the top.
For example, the contents of the third cell are the content from the first cell.
The cell is a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that hosts the `UITableView`. The custom cell implements the `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`.
I have searched through different forums and sites and found the solution of refresh.
I tried adding the `[collectionView reload]` to the `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, but it goes into constant loop. I know that is not the right place, but i do not have any other methods that cause the refresh (only scrolling through the cells loads the next cell's content).
Can somebody please help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some facts about dequeuing.
When you 3d custom `UICollectionViewCell` is dequeued, it isn't allocated like when it's displayed for the first time. Instead, your collection view "reuses" 1st cell for displaying 3d. The best moment to clear content in your custom cell class is `-(void)prepareForReuse`. If you override it and clear it's content, the `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will dequeue "clear" cell which you can further customize.
However, i don't exactly know how to "clear" the tableView, not sure whether it's possible. You have to `reloadData` on your tableView in `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. Example:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyCVCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCVCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.arrayOfURLsForDisplay = self.arrayOfArraysOfURLs[indexPath.row];
    [cell.tableView reloadData];
    return cell;
}
```

Here i mean you have some `arrayOfArraysOfURLs` in your viewController and you dislay URLs in your custom cell from some `arrayOfURLsForDisplay`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help.I had to call the method clearsContextBeforeDrawing ([cell.tableView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];)in the -(void)prepareForReuse method on the UITableView and then call the method reload ([cell.tableView reloadData]) in cellForItemAtIndexPath.It is working flawless after  changing the code as above. Your answer has been a great help(I should have posted it before I wasted lot of time trying myself). Also,I call [cell.tableView clearsContextBeforeDrawing] and reload in the cellForItemAtIndexPath it works the same way without the need for prepareforReuse,just a FYI.

Comment: Not a problem. However, general practice for using such controls (`UICollectionView` and `UITableView`) requires from you to override `-prepareForReuse` to bring cell into "default" state. In specific cases (like yours one) there could be no need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, instead of using `[cell.tableView reloadData]` inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, I called `collectionView.reloadData` in the `prepareForUse` method that is overwritten in your custom `UITableviewCell`